# Convert time from NetCDF to decimal years in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I have a NetCDF file with time in units 'hours since 1990-01-01T00:00:00Z'. I have managed to transform these data into table format (YYYY,MM,DD,hh,mm,ss). How can I transform these data in a data array with decimal years? Thanks

```
# Extract time variable
time_gmb = dataset['time'][:]
time_gmb.data;
# Convert to decimal years
time_convert = nc.num2date(time[:], time.units)
print(time_convert)
```

The data look like this and the first one (16 April 2002, 20:23:54) should be converted to 2002.29, the second (12 May 2002, 09:36:05) to 2002.36 and so on:

```
[cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2002, 4, 16, 20, 23, 54, 375000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2002, 5, 12, 9, 36, 5, 625000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2002, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2002, 9, 17, 3, 36, 5, 625000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2002, 10, 16, 8, 23, 54, 375000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2002, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2002, 12, 17, 9, 36, 5, 625000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 1, 15, 14, 23, 54, 375000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 3, 18, 15, 36, 5, 625000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 4, 16, 20, 23, 54, 375000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 5, 12, 9, 36, 5, 625000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 7, 17, 2, 23, 54, 375000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 9, 17, 3, 36, 5, 625000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 10, 16, 8, 23, 54, 375000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 12, 17, 9, 36, 5, 625000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 1, 8, 7, 40, 46, 875000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 2, 17, 13, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 3, 17, 20, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 4, 16, 3, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 5, 19, 1, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 6, 17, 8, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 7, 16, 15, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 8, 18, 13, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 9, 16, 20, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 10, 16, 3, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 11, 18, 1, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 12, 17, 8, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 1, 15, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 6, 17, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 7, 17, 2, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 9, 17, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 12, 17, 9, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 1, 15, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 6, 17, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 7, 17, 2, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 9, 17, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 12, 17, 9, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 1, 15, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 6, 17, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 7, 17, 2, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 9, 17, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 12, 17, 9, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 1, 15, 15, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 2, 17, 13, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 3, 17, 20, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 4, 16, 3, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 5, 19, 1, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 6, 17, 8, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 7, 16, 15, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 8, 18, 13, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 9, 16, 20, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 10, 16, 3, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 11, 18, 1, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 12, 17, 8, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 1, 15, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 6, 17, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 7, 17, 2, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 9, 17, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 12, 17, 9, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 1, 15, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 6, 17, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 7, 17, 2, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 9, 17, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 12, 13, 18, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 2, 17, 10, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 7, 20, 18, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 9, 17, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 10, 30, 22, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 12, 28, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 1, 15, 15, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 2, 17, 13, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 3, 17, 20, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 4, 5, 3, 50, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 6, 17, 8, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 7, 16, 15, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 8, 18, 13, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 9, 13, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 11, 18, 1, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 12, 17, 8, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 1, 15, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 4, 20, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 6, 17, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 7, 17, 2, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 12, 17, 9, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 1, 8, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 6, 14, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 9, 17, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 1, 22, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 4, 27, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 7, 17, 2, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 9, 13, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 12, 24, 16, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 1, 15, 15, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 2, 13, 22, 4, 41, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 3, 17, 20, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 5, 19, 1, 55, 18, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 6, 17, 8, 38, 26, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 7, 16, 15, 21, 33, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 8, 22, 5, 45, 56, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 11, 29, 1, 26, 15, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 12, 24, 16, 18, 45, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2017, 1, 22, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2017, 4, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2017, 4, 24, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2017, 5, 12, 9, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2017, 6, 10, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2018, 6, 17, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2018, 7, 9, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2018, 10, 30, 22, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2018, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2018, 12, 17, 9, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 1, 15, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 2, 13, 19, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 3, 18, 15, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 4, 16, 20, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 5, 16, 1, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 6, 17, 21, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 7, 17, 2, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 8, 15, 7, 12, 11, 250000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 9, 17, 3, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 10, 16, 8, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 11, 18, 4, 47, 48, 750000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 12, 17, 9, 35, 37, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 1, 15, 15, 22, 30, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 2, 17, 13, 54, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 3, 17, 20, 37, 30, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 4, 16, 3, 22, 30, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 5, 19, 1, 54, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 6, 17, 8, 37, 30, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 7, 16, 15, 22, 30, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 8, 18, 13, 54, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 9, 16, 20, 37, 30, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 10, 16, 3, 22, 30, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 11, 18, 1, 54, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 12, 17, 8, 37, 30, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2021, 1, 15, 14, 24, 22, 500000, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2021, 2, 13, 19, 11, 15, 0, has_year_zero=False)]
```

Comment: how many days should your year have? I've seen people using 360, 365, 365.25 etc.

Comment: @FObersteiner 365 days is fine!

Comment: @YoniVerhaegen If your input is hours since a reference year and each year has a fixed number of days (as you sometimes get for model data), a modulo calculation might be a good option to get fractional years, e.g. `fractional_year = total_hours % (365*24) / (365*24)`. If you want to take the "datetime route", subtract the year  (`datetime(year, 1, 1)`) from each date, and calculate the fractional year from the resulting timedelta.